# How to refresh a Tk inter window with new data from a string

Tags: python, tkinter, refresh

```
root = Tk()
prompt = (string)
label1 = Label(root.attributes("-topmost", True), text=prompt, width=(50), height=(25))
label1.pack()

def close_after_1s():
    root.destroy()

root.after(1000, close_after_1s)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what new data? Just random, made-up data? data read from a file? A process? A server? A database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe some of the others.

Perhaps the following will help. Widget options can be set after creation either by subscripting, as done below, or with, for example, `label.config(text=next(strit))`.

```
import tkinter as tk  # 3.x
root = tk.Tk()
strings = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Last', 'Closing']
strit = iter(strings)
label = tk.Label(root, text=next(strit), width=(50), height=(25))
label.pack()

def refresh():
    try:
        label['text'] = next(strit)
        root.after(1000, refresh)
    except StopIteration:
        root.destroy()

root.after(1000, refresh)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much and Merry Christmas!